# How to update array in MongoDB to Document object

Tags: mongodb

```
db.comments.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0dce535dbc47b0d8c9f23e"),
    "create" : 1577963091106,
    "update" : 1577963091106,
    "post_id" : 1,
    "user" : {
        "user_id" : "ccchhh1",
        "loginType" : "kakao",
        "user_profile_img" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBhaNckqtbF2gR0kMvWGhwe7ad4BvVAnAcHQqhgiIzp9mXSPXv4Q&s",
        "nick_name" : "test"
    },
    "comment" : "test",
    "children" : [
        {
            "parent" : ObjectId("5e0dce535dbc47b0d8c9f23e"),
            "create" : 1577963694219,
            "update" : 1577963694219,
            "post_id" : 1,
            "user" : {
                "user_id" : "ccchhh1",
                "loginType" : "kakao",
                "user_profile_img" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBhaNckqtbF2gR0kMvWGhwe7ad4BvVAnAcHQqhgiIzp9mXSPXv4Q&s",
                "nick_name" : "test"
            },
            "comment" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the document to document children with an id as the key value. However, update does not create _id. What should I do?

The result I want is

```
db.comments.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0dce535dbc47b0d8c9f23e"),
    "create" : 1577963091106,
    "update" : 1577963091106,
    "post_id" : 1,
    "user" : {
        "user_id" : "ccchhh1",
        "loginType" : "kakao",
        "user_profile_img" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBhaNckqtbF2gR0kMvWGhwe7ad4BvVAnAcHQqhgiIzp9mXSPXv4Q&s",
        "nick_name" : "test"
    },
    "comment" : "test",
    "children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("---"),------>>>>>>>> !!
            "parent" : ObjectId("5e0dce535dbc47b0d8c9f23e"),
            "create" : 1577963694219,
            "update" : 1577963694219,
            "post_id" : 1,
            "user" : {
                "user_id" : "ccchhh1",
                "loginType" : "kakao",
                "user_profile_img" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBhaNckqtbF2gR0kMvWGhwe7ad4BvVAnAcHQqhgiIzp9mXSPXv4Q&s",
                "nick_name" : "test"
            },
            "comment" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish the object that goes into children also had a _id value. I tried various things to find a way, but failed. What should I do? Help me

Comment: can you share schema of comments ?

Comment: What did you try?